# Thumbnail script won't display thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, xampp, thumbnails, generator

I am testing my wordpress themes on localhost, the problem is with automatic thumbnail script, they do not displaying thumbnail images, I tested with Xamp and I tested with Wamp, but can’t find out what is wrong with my PC. I am using Phpthumb script: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ and I have enabled the GD Library too.

Also the Wordpress built-in plugins like featured content sliders, which they automatic generated thumbnail from posts, they too not displaying the thumbnail images.

All the theme coding is correct, because the same theme is working perfectly online, when I tested that in my hosting account.

There is no thumb error message on main page.

The path to Image URL is correct.

However, when i view the source code and clicked on the thumbnail image url, than i got many error messages like: -

```
Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 152



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 160



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpthumb.class.php on line 980




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 269



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 287




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php on line 287



Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpthumb.class.php on line 1154



Deprecated:  Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpthumb.class.php on line 890




Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpthumb.functions.php on line 514


**Headers already sent in file "D:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\BizMask\phpThumb\phpThumb.php" on line "152", dumping error message as text:**


phpThumb() v1.7.9-200805132119

Headers already sent (phpThumb.php line 446)
```

and they are more than 100 of lines of these kind messages.

i don’t know what is this

Please help, I will really appreciate that.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the Wordpress Built-in Support for Thumbnails that was implemented in wordpress v2.9.

Here is a detailed guide to help you through the process:
[How to use Post Thumbnails Feature in Wordpress!](http://www.zubair.info/2010/11/19/how-to-use-post-thumbnails-feature-in-wordpress.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have php 5.3 on the server that generates these errors and php 5.2 or earlier on the server where this message don't appear?
Or you have enabled WP_DEBUG in the wp-config.php file?

I suggest that you either run php 5.2 on all servers, or use another thumbnail script.
[Timthumb](http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php) is a very good alternative.